# declare typescript type on spread results

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

i have code like so:

```js
type myType = {
  key1: string,
  optKey?: boolean,
}

const obj = {
  key1: 'hi',
  key2: 'yes',
}

const { key2, ...typedObj } = obj
typedObj.optKey = true
```

now typescript complains: `Property 'optKey' does not exist on type '{ key1: string; }'`

i'd like to inform typescript that `typedObj` is in fact an instance of `myType`. is there a way to do this, either during the `const` spread declaration, or afterwards?

this works:

```js
typedObj2 = typedObj as myType
```

but is there another way without a temporary untyped variable?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your `obj` at first, something that has to do with `myType`

Here is an example that fixes the problem.

```
type myType = {
  key1: string,
  optKey?: boolean,
}

const obj: myType & { key2: string } = {
  key1: 'hi',
  key2: 'yes',
}

const { key2, ...typedObj } = obj
typedObj.optKey = true
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAtiAq5oF4oG8BQUoGsIgEYAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMAaLKAezGAGl8B%20EgIxYsANhACGNJgF8MGAMYsa5VnwBWJOIkhQAZOlz4ATCXLV6USVFSZseQiQDkACyr2mNww5ARSrjNLkKSmj6IAYMUAB0UaCQACYA8qrmlsoqGDEQCaoRbJz4KZQArhBAA)